# How to set bootstrap datepicker date range as dynamic

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and jquery datepair js. When user selects from date then i want to display 30 days ahead to the from date. Ex: if user selects 2015-09-10 then in to date field i want 2015-10-20 like that. Means 30 days ahead from the user selected date.For this i am using the below code.

```
jQuery('#datepair_range .date').datepicker({
'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
'todayHighlight': true,
'endDate': '+30d',
'autoclose': true
});
jQuery('#datepair_range').datepair();
```

But in calendar user able to select date with in the 30 days date range. After 30 days all dates are disabled. Adding 'endDate': '+30d', is this wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this one by using the below code.

```
jQuery('#datepair_range .date').datepicker({
'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
'todayHighlight': true,
'autoclose': true
});


var dynamic_date_range = document.getElementById('datepair_range');
var ddynamic_date_range_pair = new Datepair(dynamic_date_range, {
'defaultDateDelta': 365
});
```

Now the output will be 365 days will add to the from date.(user selected date)